# TabBar Remaining after closing TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a app where the initial screen is a viewcontroller. In the vc, I have a button that opens a popup TabBarController. However, when I close that popup, the Tab bar still is still there. Basically, I am trying to dismiss the TabBarController, so that the tabBar dissapears. I don't want to just hide the TabBar, I want it to go away.
Thanks.

Here's how I present the TabBarController as a popup

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabBarController") as! MyTabBarController 
self.addChild(vc)
vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
vc.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Throwing a bounty at it doesn’t make the question any clearer.

Comment: How are you presenting your tab bar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
vc.view.removeFromSuperView()
```

from parent viewcontroller or just called `dismiss` from `MyTabBarController`